# Insert iframe at chrome.tabs.onActivated

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to insert an iframe when chrome.tabs.onActivated gets triggered when going to already opened tabs.

I'm developing an extension that does the `chrome.scripting.executeScript` on all tabs in the browser at initialization.

I'm registering message listeners on the content script and the background.

From the popup extension, I'm clicking a button that tells the content script to insert an iframe.

On the current page it works. If I open a new page it works. But when I'm going to an existent tab, nothing happens in the content scripts.
In the background the console logs are showing I'm on the correct tab. Only if I refresh the existent open tab, the iframe is inserted.

I've tried injecting the scripts again at onActivated, but nothing happens.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Later edit:

It seems that I had a faulty condition in my `chrome.scripting.executeScript` and the scripts were never programatically inserted. They were inserted from the manifest.json

I don't need to insert the scripts again on onActivated, as they are inserted by executeScript.

Comment: The question is unanswerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve) because there's a lot of places where you could have made a mistake, it's not a trivial issue.

Comment: I was asking more as an architecture point of view / steps to be taken.

Comment: The architecture will always be the same: the popup, the background script, the content script + communication. The approach you described is perfectly fine if implemented correctly, so there must be a mistake e.g. maybe you use onActivated inside the popup which won't work because the popup doesn't run when not shown. It's a typical debugging question that needs an MCVE to become answerable. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.